# Android How to duplicate a EditText Drawable Background?

Tags: java, android, drawable, background-color

I want to change the background color of my edittext when validation fails to a redish color and then, when the user starts to correct it, return the original color.

The EditText has rounded borders, therefore using *setBackgroundColor( )* does not work here, because it draws an ugly rectangle instead of the nice rounded rectangle.

I tried to save the background and restore it afterwards. And use a new bakground to paint it red. The code below does not work, because *tv.getBackground( )* returns the same reference to both **originalBg** and **errorBg**. When I set the color filter to **errorBg** I actually change it for **originalBg** too.

How can I **duplicate** the background object into **errorBg** so I can change the color there?

```js
    final Drawable originalBg = tv.getBackground();
    final Drawable errorBg = tv.getBackground();   <-- this does not create a new Drawable, just the same reference
    errorBg.setColorFilter(0xFFff6347, Mode.MULTIPLY);
    tv.setBackgroundDrawable(errorBg);
    tv.invalidate();
    tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            tv.setBackgroundDrawable(originalBg);
            tv.invalidate();
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the color filter with setColorFilter(null)

```
tv.getBackgroundDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFff6347, Mode.MULTIPLY);
tv.invalidate();
tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
               tv.getBackgroundDrawable().setColorFilter(null);
               tv.invalidate();
   }
```

Comment: That's it. It worked perfectly! (I used tv.getBackground( ) since tv.getBackgroundDrawable( ) does not exist) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a copy:

```
 final Drawable originalBg = tv.getBackground();
 final BitmapDrawable errorBg = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), (BitmapDrawable) tv.getBackground();
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not have to test your suggestion, ab11's solution was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an xml file which defines a drawable with rounded corners to use as your background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ff6347"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

Put this file in your drawables folder and use the `setBackgroundDrawable()` method on your EditText to use it.  You may need to play around with the color and corner radius to get it how you'll want it.  Not exactly the answer to your question, but hopefully it can help.

Comment: I don't want to create a new shape, the shape is there already.